# Drupal 7 $comment object enumeration

Tags: php, drupal

I need a listing of all of the members of the (or any instance of) $comment object.  What's the best way to generate this?  Is there a place in the Drupal source code where the definition is easy to find (I looked, but came up dry)?

Something like this is for the $node object: http://drupal.org/node/49768 (only without the descriptions of course).

Comment: what does `print_r($comment);` give you?

Comment: Maybe this is because i'm implementing _hook_comment_presave($comment)_ and it doesn't have all of it's attributes yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could send $comment through the [Devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel)'s [dpm()](http://api.lullabot.com/dpm) function:

```
dpm($comment);
```

Comment: Good call.  That's probably a module I should have started using a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Try [comment_load_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_load_multiple/7)

```
<?php
  $conditions = array("pid" => $comment_you_want_the_children_of->id);
  comment_load_multiple(array(), $conditions);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. get Drupal for Firebug -
   http://drupal.org/project/drupalforfirebug - also contains a link to the Drupal for Firebug Firefox extension that
   works with Firebug.  This will save
   you a lot of pain when you need to
   dump data.  You simply write
   somewhere into the code
   `firep($someVar)` and the dump will
   be displayed in the appropriate
   Firebug pane.
2. Go to your theme, and find the
   appropriate template for comments -
   comment.tpl.php (if you're using the
   tpl.php type theme engine).  This
   would be the right spot for you to
   try "dumping" the comment variable -
   insert at the top firep($comment);
   this will show you the full comment
   object.

Here's a dump from a Drupal 6 install, Drupal 7 may be different:

```
stdClass Object
(
[cid] => 1676
[pid] => 0
[nid] => 1672
[subject] => Comment Body
[comment] =>

Comment Body


[format] => 1
[timestamp] => 1300904186
[name] => admin
[mail] =>
[homepage] =>
[uid] => 1
[registered_name] => admin
[signature] =>
[signature_format] => 0
[picture] => sites/default/files/pictures/picture-1.jpg
[data] => a:7:{s:17:"messaging_default";s:4:"mail";s:6:"preset";s:18:"atrium_user_simple";s:14:"picture_delete";s:0:"";s:14:"picture_upload";s:0:"";s:13:"form_build_id";s:37:"form-5ab3ec10bc31bce9da52e443b0fa0651";s:27:"notifications_send_interval";s:1:"0";s:16:"comment_settings";s:0:"";}
[thread] => 01/
[status] => 0
[messaging_default] => mail
[preset] => atrium_user_simple
[picture_delete] =>
[picture_upload] =>
[form_build_id] => form-5ab3ec10bc31bce9da52e443b0fa0651
[notifications_send_interval] => 0
[comment_settings] =>
[depth] => 0
[new] => 0
)
```